# Ajuda submenus html

Tags: html

Olá, estou em um projeto aqui, mas travei aqui em uma parte, precisa de ajuda de vocês, é o seguinte, eu tenho o codigo mostrado abaixo, e quero fazer tipo igual a esse mais criar um submenu...

```
<li>
    <br>
    <a href="dashboard.php" class=" active">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard sidebar-nav-icon"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-nav-mini-hide">Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta e dar exemplos do que queres que apareça?

Comment: Olhe as seguintes imagens:
1° como está: http://imgur.com/a/HqJxM
2° como e para ficar: http://imgur.com/a/INYEk
Ficar tipo uns sub menu

Comment: Vou dar uma dica bacana!
Fazer as coisas na mão é legal, porém, precisamos visualizar alguns exemplos para pegar o jeito.
Visite sites como: - https://codepen.io/tanvirhasan93/pen/rgumB - http://cssdeck.com/ - https://getbootstrap.com/ Lá você vai ver diversos códigos abertos para que você possa seguir.
Para um submenu, essa sua estrutura não esta nem um pouco legal.